# Get largest page id by title?

Tags: pages

Assuming there are a few pages with same title, how to get id of the page that has the largest id (newest)? I have tried `get_page_by_title`, but it returns the smallest id (oldest).

Comment: Why don't you query the pages by title, order by published date then get the first item of result?

Answer (score 1):

By using wp_query you can have more control:

```
$title = "your title"
$q = new WP_Query (array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'title' => $title,
        ));
```

And then you can iterate through, but because we used posts per page 1 you'll get only 1 item. By default wp query displays the last first by date, you can change this with the orderby argument. Check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
while ($q->have_posts()){
            $q->the_post();
            the_title();
        }
```

Edit: if you'll use this somewhere where you need your main loop after this code snippet, reset the loop with this:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       $pages = get_pages(
array (
    'parent'  => 0, 
    'orderby' => 'id', 
    'order' => 'ASC',

)
```

);
then from the variable $pages get the 0th element from the array

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any Wordpress functions for that, but you can do it in your own way based on the original function:

```
/*
* FUNC BASED ON Wordpress function: get_page_by_title ON post.php
*/

function custom_get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output = OBJECT,$post_type = 'page' ) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_array( $post_type ) ) {
        $post_type = esc_sql( $post_type );
        $post_type_in_string = "'" . implode( "','", $post_type ) . "'";
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT ID
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title = %s
            AND post_type IN ($post_type_in_string)
            ORDER BY ID DESC
        ", $page_title );
    } else {
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT ID
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title = %s
            AND post_type = %s
            ORDER BY ID DESC
        ", $page_title, $post_type );
    }

    $page = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

    if ( $page ) {
        return get_post( $page, $output );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to ignore post status and so on?